# Django models and multilingual websites

Tags: python, django, django-models, multilingual

I have a model that has multiple text properties - title, short and long description etc. I want to have multilanguage site so I need a way to easy by able to add new languages and translations for this field for every item. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has built-in support for I18N (read internationalization):

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/

Some possible multilingual model candidates:

- http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual-model/
- http://and-other-things.blogspot.com/2009/04/list-of-django-multilingual-model.html

Comment: I know this but as far as I know i18n is used to translate static text. In my case I want users to be able to write these text in multiple languages for single object.

Comment: Included a link to list of 9 django add-ons for multiple languages in models. I haven't tried any of these yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that django transmeta, also listed by The Myyn is actually quite right for what llian is looking for. We have a very similar setup in production for some of our high traffic websites.